# How to set upper left corner icon to Google profile avatar image for Chrome on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, avatar

How to set upper left corner icon to my Google profile avatar image for Chrome on Ubuntu Linux?

When I use multiple user account in Chrome, there is an icon showing up at the upperleft corner of the Chrome window. Is there a way to set it to the profile avatar image I use in my Google profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Quit Chrome (ensure you don't have any running).
2. Go to the Chrome user profile directory `~/.config/google-chrome/`).
3. Put your new avatar png file into the "Default" subdirectory.
4. Open/edit the "Local State" file in a good text editor.
5. Find the "profile" section; it resembles this:

   ```
      "profile": {
         "info_cache": {
            "Default": {
               "avatar_icon": "chrome://theme/IDR_PROFILE_AVATAR_7",
   ```
6. Ignore the "avatar_icon" line - it's not what you want!
7. Edit the "Default" profile section and add the following lines (I put them in the right alphabetical order amongst the other lines; I'm not sure whether that matters):

   > `"gaia_picture_file_name": "`*your-icon-file-name*`.png",`
   >               `"has_migrated_to_gaia_info": true,`
   >               `"use_gaia_picture": true,`
8. Save the "Local State" file.
9. Start Chrome.

If you want to do this for other profiles, just do the above steps for a different directory besides "Default" (for example, "Profile 1").

I had run Chrome with the `--gaia-profile-info` switch before I tried the above, so you may need to do that first, but I'm not sure.

You may want to star the Chrome issue 91230 http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91230 to get a proper UI for this type of thing again.

(I also answered this at [How do I access/edit the Chrome user avatar images?](https://superuser.com/a/639248/250287) on Super User.)