# "Google Profile.ico" not created

Tags: google-chrome, windows-vista, chromium

I created a new profile in Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.40 beta-m.  Unlike other profiles, it did not get a custom desktop icon with its profile icon over the Chrome icon ("Google Profile.ico").  I have checked in:

- `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\[PROFILE]`
- `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
- `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\24.0.1312.40\chrome.dll`

I have read http://blog.steelendeavor.com/2012/11/chrome-profile-shortcuts.html, [How do I access/edit the Chrome user avatar images?](https://superuser.com/questions/449244/how-do-i-access-edit-the-chrome-user-avatar-images), and some other material.

Is there somewhere I have not looked where I might find the custom icon for new user profiles?  Does Chrome still create these automatically?  Is there a way to force Chrome to make them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspicious that you have to have multiple profiles for the button to show up, or maybe wait a bit. Chrome has an "Add desktop shortcut" button on the add/edit user screen: `Settings > "People" section > [select a profile] > Edit`.  This causes "Google profile.ico" to appear where you first expected, `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\[PROFILE]`

[image]

Comment: Chrome 26 does create icons for new user profiles.  Now if I could find a way to create icons for already existing profiles, I would be all set.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: You bet :)  Not sure about 26, but in 27 you can find the same "Add desktop shortcut" button if you go to settings, select the profile, and click Edit. Good luck!

Comment: Turns out that it's there in Chrome 26 (Version 26.0.1410.64 m) as well!  It just takes a few seconds for Chrome to load the button in the "Edit user" dialog.  If there is already an icon for that user profile on the Desktop, even manually created, then Chrome will present a "Remove desktop shortcut" button instead of an "Add desktop shortcut" button.